# Generate an array of char* pointers from a function

Tags: c++

I have a C++ function to which I have to pass `char* arguments[]`. The prototype of this function is as follows:
`void somefunc(char* arguments[])`

To pass the above array to this function, I am generating this array from another function which can return me this `char* array` output, and this looks somehwhat like this.

```
char** genArgs(int numOfArgs,...)
{
    va_list argList;    
    char** toRet = new char*[numOfArgs];
    va_start (arguments, numOfArgs);
    for(int cnt = 0; cnt < numOfArgs ; ++cnt)
        toRet[cnt] = va_arg(argList, char*);

    va_end(arguments);
}
```

I am confused how to actually write the above function correctly, given that I will be passing the inputs to function something like : `genArgs(3, a.c_str(), b.c_str(), c.c_str())` or `genArgs(2, a.c_str(), b.c_str())` 
How can I generate the above char* array without using char** (since this would have to be deleted before returning from the function to avoid memory leak).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your declaration of `genArgs`, it seems that whenever you call `genArgs`, you know how many arguments you want to pass. Is this correct? If so (and if you are using `C++11`) then you can use `std::array` in the calling function. So instead of this:

```
char** arglist = genArgs (4, "MyArg1", mYaRG2", "LastArg", 0) ;
somefunc (arglist) ;
delete[] arglist ;
```

you can do it this way:

```
#include <array>
std::array<char*, 4> arglist { "MyArg1", mYaRG2", "LastArg", 0 } ;
somefunc (&arglist[0]) ;
```

But there is really nothing wrong with the first solution, unless you are a C++ ascetic. (However, you do need a `return toRet ;` statement in `genArgs`!)

Answer (score 2):

> this would have to be deleted before returning from the function to avoid memory leak

This is not entirely correct: although it is true that you need to eventually `delete[]` the pointer that you allocated with `new[]`, you do not necessarily have to do it before exiting the function where the allocation happened.

You can do this:

```
// This allocates args; we now own the pointer
char **argsToPass = genArgs(2, a.c_str(), b.c_str());
// Make the call as usual
somefunc(argsToPass);
// Now that args are no longer needed, we delete them:
delete [] argsToPass;
```

Comment: Just make sure you put it in "genArgs" contract (Header Description) that the caller is responsible for deleting returned data. Think about it this way, you're making your own malloc function!

Answer (score 0):

The usual way would be to use an object that manages the lifetime of the array (such as a `std::vector<char*>` or a `std::unique_ptr<char*[]>`), and then to return that (so that the eventual release of the memory would be guaranteed by the type system):

```
std::vector<char*> genArgs(int numOfArgs,...)
{
    std::vector<char*> toRet;
    toRet.reserve(numOfArgs);
    va_list argList;
    va_start(argList, numOfArgs);
    for(int cnt = 0; cnt < numOfArgs ; ++cnt) {
        toRet.push_back(va_arg(argList, char*));
    }
    va_end(arguments);
    return toRet;
}
```

To use this, do the following:

```
somefunc(&genArgs(3, a.c_str(), b.c_str(), c.c_str()).front());
```